# python convert list of dictionaries to an key value where each key will have unique values in array

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts:

```
data = [
    {'Name': 'A', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.2},
    {'Name': 'B', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.75},
    {'Name': 'CC', 'City': 'C2', 'Rate': 2.3},
    {'Name': 'A', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.2},
]
```

How to convert this to the following:

```
result = {
    'Name': ['A','B','CC'], 
    'City': ['C1','C2'], 
    'Rate': [2.2,2.75,2.3]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the dictionaries in your list, and then the key-value pairs in your dictionaries to push the values into a `defaultdict` of type `set`. This will ensure only unique values are kept

Also don't name your variable `list`, that will cause problems. `list` is a reserved keyword used by python that you're overriding

```
import collections

l = [                                                                                                                                   
 {'Name': 'A', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.2},                                                                                               
 {'Name': 'B', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.75},                                                                                              
 {'Name': 'CC', 'City': 'C2', 'Rate': 2.3},                                                                                              
 {'Name': 'A', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.2},                                                                                               
 ]

d = collections.defaultdict(set)

for entry in l:
     for k,v in entry.items():
         d[k].add(v)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(set,
            {'Name': {'A', 'B', 'CC'},
             'City': {'C1', 'C2'},
             'Rate': {2.2, 2.3, 2.75}})
```

The `d = collections.defaultdict(set)` is a shortcut to the following code:

```
d = {
    'Name':set(),
    'City':set(),
    'Rate':set(),
}
```

But it's even more handy since you don't have to specify the keys (Name, City, Rate) in advance

Comment: Thank you. This works as expected. 
Can you please point me to some reference as why its working as expected. I assume this statement is helping to get unique values. d = collections.defaultdict(set)

Comment: You're right that's the crux of everything. I've added some text describing what defaultdict is doing above. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You could use zip on the items of all the dicts, and using `dict.fromkeys` will remove duplicates preserving order as you intend. All that used in a comprehension like so:

```
result = {k: list(dict.fromkeys(v)) for (k, *_), v in map(zip, *map(dict.items, data))}
```

*In a more readable format:*

```
result = {
    k: list(dict.fromkeys(v)) 
    for (k, *_), v 
    in map(zip, *map(dict.items, data))
}
```

Result

```
{'Name': ['A', 'B', 'CC'], 'City': ['C1', 'C2'], 'Rate': [2.2, 2.75, 2.3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all dictionaries have the same keys, you can do this in a dictionary comprehension based on the keys (of the first item):

```
data = [
    {'Name': 'A', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.2},
    {'Name': 'B', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.75},
    {'Name': 'CC', 'City': 'C2', 'Rate': 2.3},
    {'Name': 'A', 'City': 'C1', 'Rate': 2.2},
]

result = { k:[d[k] for d in data] for k in data[0] }

print(result)
{'Name': ['A', 'B', 'CC', 'A'],
 'City': ['C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1'],
 'Rate': [2.2, 2.75, 2.3, 2.2]}
```

If all the keys are in the same order, you can use zip on unpacked values of the dictionaries:

```
result = dict(zip(data[0],zip(*map(dict.values,data))))
```

*(this produces tuples instead of lists though)*